# Get the variable value from a previous struct in arrays of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the following struct:

```
struct V {
    int d;
    int tip;
    char naziv[10];
    int veza;
    int tezina;
};
typedef struct V Vertex;
```

The following declaration:

```
void kreiranje(Vertex cvorovi[]);
```

The following main function:

```
int main(){
    int n=15;
    Vertex cvorovi[n];
    Vertex *pokazivac = &cvorovi[n];
    kreiranje(pokazivac);
}
```

And this is the code behind the kreiranje function:

```
void kreiranje(Vertex cvorovi[])
{
   int x,y,d,f,g;
   int i = 0;
   int brojac = 0;
   char z[10];
   char line[50];
   char lined[50];
   FILE *fr;
   FILE *fp;
   fr = fopen ("nodes.txt", "rt");  
   fp = fopen ("edges.txt", "rt");

   while(fgets(line, 50, fr) != NULL)
   {
     sscanf (line, "%d|%d %s", &x, &y, &z);
     cvorovi[n].d = x;
     cvorovi[n].tip = y;
     strcpy(cvorovi[n].naziv, z);

     if(brojac < n){

        fgets(lined, 50, fp) != NULL;
        sscanf (lined, "%d-%d,%d", &d, &f, &g);
        if (cvorovi[n-1].d == d){
            printf ("\n Cvor prosli je %d\n", cvorovi[n-1].d);
            printf ("\n %d \n", d);
            cvorovi[n].veza = y;
            cvorovi[n].tezina = g;

         }
         else {
                cvorovi[n].veza = y;
                cvorovi[n].tezina = g;
         } 
    }
   brojac++;
   }
   fclose(fr);  
   fclose(fp);
}
```

The files are like this:

```
edges.txt
1-2,4
1-3,5

nodes.txt
1|1 EL_01
2|2 TF_01
```

In the first line of `nodes.txt`, first number presents the ID, that is used in `edges.txt`. My problem is the following - how can I check and assign if the ID has more than one of the connections that are given in the `edges.txt` (just like the example shows)?

The file values read okay, however I am not sure how can I get the previous member's of the struct values to use with comparison.

Comment: where is `n`? also, `Vertex *pokazivac = &cvorovi[n];` is terribly wrong.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I forgot to include that, I will edit it in a moment. I am not a C programmer and I'm sorry for the bad code, could you please elaborate on why is that statement wrong?

Comment: The statement (and all others in that function referring to `cvorovi[n]`) is wrong because there is no variable `n` in scope in that function.  I think you mean `*cvorovi` or `cvorovi[0]` (which are equivalent inside function `kreiranje()`).

Comment: Additionally, it looks like your function is virtually certain to evoke undefined behavior by writing past the end of array `cvorovi`, as what you actually pass to the function is a pointer to the first position *after* its end.

Comment: Side note: the function names, variable names and printed strings in your code make it difficult to read. You need to put some effort translating it to the most common language among SO users (hint: it's not Chinese). Also, try to provide a minimal piece of code which illustrates the exact problem that you're experiencing.

Comment: Is it a question about validating nodes and edges? Like no edge is using an undefined vertex and (maybe) no disconnected nodes and no duplicate edges?

Comment: @JohnBollinger In my head the variable `n` would have presented the size of the array of `Vertex` structs. If I was to put `cvorovi[0]` How would I pass the values of the entire array of structs, instead of a pointer to the first element?

Comment: @barakmanos I apologize. Should I edit the values, because that might create extra work for the people who already replied?

Comment: @NickZavaritsky The question was just to create the graph from the two files.

Comment: In your code, variable `n` is local to function `main()`.  It is not accessible in other functions, though you can pass its value to other functions as demonstrated in my answer.  Moreover you don't *want* to pass all the array elements by value; you *do* want to pass a pointer to the array (which is equivalent to a pointer to its first element).  That allows your function to initialize the elements in such a way that they are accessible in `main()` after your function returns.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is the following - how can I check and assign if the ID has more than one of the connections that are given in the edges.txt (just like the example shows)?

There are several ways to represent a graph in programs. I think in your case the easiest would be [Adjacency Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) or [Incidence Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix):

```
int AdjacencyMatrix[n][n];
```

somewhere in main():
    memset(AdjacencyMatrix, 0, sizeof(AdjacencyMatrix));

In your reader function (kreiranje):

```
fgets(lined, 50, fp) != NULL;
sscanf (lined, "%d-%d,%d", &d, &f, &g);
int From=d;
int To=f;
AdjacencyMatrix[From][To]=1
AdjacencyMatrix[To][From]=1; <<- Only if this is undirected graph
```

then,
if you want to check node's X connections, use this:

```
for(i=0;i<n;++i) {
    if(AdjacencyMatrix[X][i]==1) {
        printf("Node %d links to %d\n", X, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want something a bit more like this:

```
/* ... data type and function declarations ... */

#define MAX_VERTICES 15

int main() {
    Vertex cvorovi[MAX_VERTICES];
    int n;

    /* arguments are a pointer to the array _start_, plus its size: */
    /* the number of vertices actually read is returned */
    n = kreiranje(cvorovi, MAX_VERTICES);

    /* ... */

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
int kreiranje(Vertex cvorovi[], int n) {
    int brojac = 0;
    /* ... other local variable declarations ... */

    while ((brojac < n) && (fgets(line, 50, fr) != NULL)) {
        /* ... loop body ... */
        brojac++;
    }

    return brojac;
}
```

I suggest having function `kreiranje()` return the number of vertices actually read, as shown, because you will need to know that to do anything further with them.

As to checking for multiple connections attributed to the same ID, you keep track of what you've read so far, and you read until you've seen enough to be confident that reading more is unnecessary.  I know that's very abstract, but the details depend on the assumptions you can make about the form and organization of your data, and on the data structures you use in your program.  If you're asking about a general approach to your problem rather than about details of how to implement it, then your question is probably inappropriate for SO.

Comment: Note that `kreiranje(cvorovi, MAX_VERTICES)` is exactly equivalent to `kreiranje(&cvorovi[0], MAX_VERTICES)`.